# Why does it say that the tree is null even though I inserted values?

Tags: c

I am trying to work on a binary search tree program. This is my main program. Every time I try to print Inorder traversal of the values I inserted into the tree, the printInorder function says that it's empty or null. I'm aware that the root is initialized to NULL but how do I let function know that the tree is not empty?

```
void main()
{
    int pgS, ch;
    char chT[MAX], chT2[MAX];
    treePtr root = NULL;

    menu();
    scanf("%d",&ch);

    switch(ch)
    {
        case 1:
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nName of the Content: "); 
            gets(chT); 
            printf("\nPage of the content above: "); 
            scanf("%d",&pgS);
            insert(root,pgS,chT); 
            system("cls");  
            main();
            break;
        case 2:
            system("cls");
            printInOrder(root);
            Sleep(5000);
            main(); 
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\nSearch Content: ");
            gets(chT2);
            search(root,chT2);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Some of the functions, maybe it can help.

```
treePtr insert(treePtr p, elementType noP, char *Incontent){ //insert elements in the tree
    if(p==NULL) {p=createTree(Incontent,noP);}
    else {
        if(p->pages > noP){
            p->left=insert(p->left,noP,Incontent);
            p->part=Incontent;
            p->pages=noP;
        }
        else if (p->pages <noP){
            p->right=insert(p->right,noP,Incontent);
        p->part=Incontent;
            p->pages=noP;

        }
    } return p;
}
void printInOrder(treePtr p){
    if (p == NULL){printf("Empty");}
    else {
    printInOrder(p->left);
    printf("\nTABLE OF CONTENTS\n%s\t\t %d ", p->part,p->pages);
    printInOrder(p->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: format a bit your first code snippet. As it is in unreadable

Comment: Probably not the root case of the issue you are facing, but still this `fflush(stdin)` invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: `void main` is wrong; `main` must return `int`. `gets` should not be used. `getch` and `Sleep` are not standard C functions. Calling `main` recursively is crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `insert` function calls `createTree` to assign a new instance to the `p` variable, but you don't assign this variable to the `root` variable in your `main` function, so `root` remains `NULL` after the function returns (i.e. `root = insert(root, ...)` would work).

Or, you could simply create the root node tree before calling insert (i.e. `root = createTree(...);`). Nevertheless, a `main` function recursively calling itself is a bad idea.